# How to add edited date automatically to datetimepicker?

Tags: vb.net

I want to make the time will fill automatically in Datetimepicker when I edit the price of my product. So, it can compare to the date of buying. So, I decided to use on_update_current_timestamp in MySQL database. My problem is how to convert a string into a date in Datagridview. Because when I was press the edit button it works but for the add button it's getting an error **unable to convert MySQL date/time** Is it have any solution to achieve my goal. If yes can u explain it. Thank u

```
Public Sub disp_data()
            cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from produk"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Sub

Private Sub tambah_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tambah_btn.Click
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = $"insert into produk values('{kode.Text}','{nama.Text}','{harga.Text}','{DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")}')"

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        kode.Text = ""
        nama.Text = ""
        harga.Text = ""

        disp_data()
        MessageBox.Show("Data berhasil ditambahkan")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use string concatenation or string interpolation to build SQL code. Do it properly, i.e. use parameters, and then issues regarding format won't occur in the first place. Read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) and do it the proper way and there will be no issue.

Comment: If you want just the date portion of a `DateTime` value then use its `Date` property, which returns a new `DateTime` value with the same date and the time zeroed. Use `DateTimePicker1.Value.Date` and assign that to the `Value` of your parameter when you have implemented it.

Comment: I note it. thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it (and it's better) like this:

```vb
        '...
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into produk values (@kode,@nama,@harga,@date)"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kode", kode.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nama", nama.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@harga", harga.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        '...
```

let me know if it solves it, or if some adjustments are needed